# rasterio doesn't import to local dask cluster

Tags: python, dask, jupyter-lab, gdal, rasterio

I am running an analysis on a large number of rasters with Dask in a Jupyter Lab notebook on a Windows computer. When I run my analysis using Coiled (cloud cluster), the analysis runs fine. However, when I run the analysis on a local Dask cluster with `from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster` , `local_cluster = LocalCluster()`, I get an error that ends with the below when I run the code. It seems like the workers in the local cluster aren't able to import rasterio or gdal for some reason.

```
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\carbon_notebook\Lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py:28
     24                     os.add_dll_directory(os.path.abspath(p))
     27 from rasterio._show_versions import show_versions
---> 28 from rasterio._version import gdal_version, get_geos_version, get_proj_version
     29 from rasterio.crs import CRS
     30 from rasterio.drivers import driver_from_extension, is_blacklisted

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _version: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

In order to import rasterio into my Jupyter Lab notebook, I'm importing it with the following, which doesn't cause any errors and allows for successful usage in Coiled.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import rasterio
```

The lines below are where rasterio is introduced:

```
with rasterio.open(uri) as ds:
    return ds.read(1, window=rasterio.windows.from_bounds(*bounds, ds.transform))
```

When I run `dask.compute` on a function that includes `rasterio.open` , the local cluster returns the above error at the end of a lengthy Jupyter Lab stack trace. I'd assumed that I'd be able to run my analysis in a local cluster the same as in a Coiled cluster but that's not the case.

The packages in my notebook are as follows. To be clear, I can import rasterio to my Jupyter notebook just fine. The problem is with using it in a local Dask cluster. Any idea why I can't use rasterio in a local Dask cluster? Thanks very much.

And please let me know if I should provide other background information.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
affine                    2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.8.5           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
aiosignal                 1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py311ha68e1ae_3    conda-forge
arrow                     1.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-lru                 2.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             4.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
aws-c-auth                0.7.0                h15a3724_3    conda-forge
aws-c-cal                 0.6.0                h6ba3258_0    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.8.23               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
aws-c-compression         0.2.17               h420beca_1    conda-forge
aws-c-event-stream        0.3.1                had47b81_1    conda-forge
aws-c-http                0.7.11               h72ba615_0    conda-forge
aws-c-io                  0.13.28              ha35c040_0    conda-forge
aws-c-mqtt                0.9.0                h4941efa_0    conda-forge
aws-c-s3                  0.3.13               he04eaa7_2    conda-forge
aws-c-sdkutils            0.1.12               h420beca_0    conda-forge
aws-checksums             0.1.16               h420beca_1    conda-forge
aws-crt-cpp               0.21.0               h4a8302c_2    conda-forge
aws-sdk-cpp               1.10.57             hc0abff2_18    conda-forge
babel                     2.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backoff                   2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bleach                    6.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blosc                     1.21.4               hdccc3a2_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     3.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.78.0               h9f4b32c_3    conda-forge
boto3                     1.28.24            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
botocore                  1.31.24            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
branca                    0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                hcfcfb64_9    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                hcfcfb64_9    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py311ha68e1ae_1005    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0  
c-ares                    1.19.1               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            h56e8100_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            hdecc03f_1016    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.7.22          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py311h7d9ee11_3    conda-forge
cfitsio                   4.2.0                h9ebe7e4_0    conda-forge
cftime                    1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.6           win_pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cloudpickle               2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
coiled                    0.9.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorcet                  3.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.1.0           py311h005e61a_0    conda-forge
cryptography              41.0.3          py311h28e9c30_0    conda-forge
curl                      8.2.1                hd5e4a3a_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.12.2          py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
dask                      2023.8.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2023.8.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-geopandas            0.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
datashader                0.15.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
datashape                 0.5.4                      py_1    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.8           py311h12c1d0e_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
distributed               2023.8.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
exceptiongroup            1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.5.0                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
filelock                  3.12.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fiona                     1.9.4           py311h4e4dc46_0    conda-forge
flit-core                 3.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
folium                    0.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               hbde0cde_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.42.0          py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
fqdn                      1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               h546665d_1    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.6                h67ca5e6_1    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.4.0           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    2023.6.0           pyh1a96a4e_0    conda-forge
gdal                      3.7.0           py311h68c9619_3    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.13.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
geopandas-base            0.13.2             pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
geos                      3.11.2               h1537add_0    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.7.1               h4e61e90_11    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.1               h5728263_0    conda-forge
gilknocker                0.4.1           py311h9a9e57f_2    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.15               h1334946_6    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.14.1          nompi_h73e8ff5_100    conda-forge
icu                       72.1                 h63175ca_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        6.8.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        6.8.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.2.0         h57928b3_49496    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.25.1             pyh6817e22_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.14.0             pyh08f2357_0    conda-forge
ipywidgets                8.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
isoduration               20.11.0            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jmespath                  1.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.14             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsondiff                  2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonpointer               2.0                        py_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.19.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-with-format-nongpl 4.19.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.3.1           py311h1ea47a8_0    conda-forge
jupyter_events            0.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jupyter_server            2.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab                4.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.24.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.5.1                h96def13_4    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py311h005e61a_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.1               heb0366b_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.15                 h3e3b177_1    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230125.3      cxx17_h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libaec                    1.0.6                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
libarchive                3.6.2                h6f8411a_1    conda-forge
libarrow                  12.0.1           ha06dc20_8_cpu    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                hcfcfb64_9    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                hcfcfb64_9    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                hcfcfb64_9    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.2.1                hd5e4a3a_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.18                 hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.12               h3671451_1    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0  
libgdal                   3.7.0                h123a834_3    conda-forge
libglib                   2.76.4               he8f3873_0    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud           2.12.0               hbc1b25b_1    conda-forge
libgrpc                   1.56.2               hea2d5f7_0    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.2           nocuda_h15da153_1008    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             2.1.5.1              hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             hf2ab4e4_1015    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.9.2           nompi_h5902ca5_107    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h19919ed_0    conda-forge
libpq                     15.4                 h43585b0_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               4.23.3               h1975477_0    conda-forge
librttopo                 1.1.0               he1da8c1_13    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h39d44d4_4    conda-forge
libspatialite             5.0.1               hf8d749d_27    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h7dfc565_0    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.18.1               h06f6336_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                h6c8260b_0    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                h82a8f57_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.1                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.5               hc3477c8_0    conda-forge
libzip                    1.9.2                h519de47_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
line-profiler             4.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
llvmlite                  0.40.1          py311h5bc0dda_0    conda-forge
locket                    1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
lz4                       4.3.2           py311haddf500_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              he774522_1000    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
mapclassify               2.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.7.1           py311h6e989c2_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mdurl                     0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.1.0           h6a75c08_874    conda-forge
msgpack-python            1.0.5           py311h005e61a_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
multidict                 6.0.4           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
multipledispatch          0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
munch                     4.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            7.7.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
noise                     1.2.2           py311ha68e1ae_1004    conda-forge
notebook-shim             0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.57.1          py311h2c0921f_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.24.4          py311h0b4df5a_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                ha2aaf27_2    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.2                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
orc                       1.9.0                hf2b8f0d_1    conda-forge
overrides                 7.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.3           py311hf63dbb6_1    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
param                     1.13.0             pyh1a96a4e_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
partd                     1.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.40                h17e33f8_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.0.0          py311hde623f7_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.2.1          py311haa95532_0  
pixman                    0.40.0               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pooch                     1.7.0              pyha770c72_3    conda-forge
poppler                   23.05.0              h45d20d0_1    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.12               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
postgresql                15.4                 hc80876b_0    conda-forge
proj                      9.2.1                h660b3b0_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.17.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.39             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.39               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.5           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               hcd874cb_1001    conda-forge
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   12.0.1          py311h6a6099b_8_cpu    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyct                      0.4.6                      py_0    conda-forge
pyct-core                 0.4.6                      py_0    conda-forge
pygeos                    0.14            py311h343093d_1    conda-forge
pygments                  2.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 23.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    3.6.0           py311hcff2a09_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyh0701188_6    conda-forge
pystac                    1.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.11.4               he1021f5_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-json-logger        2.0.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.11                    2_cp311    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   304             py311h12c1d0e_2    conda-forge
pywinpty                  2.0.11          py311h12c1d0e_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0             py311ha68e1ae_5    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.1          py311h7b3f143_0    conda-forge
rasterio                  1.3.8           py311h58bba51_0    conda-forge
re2                       2023.03.02           hd4eee63_0    conda-forge
referencing               0.30.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.5.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rioxarray                 0.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rpds-py                   0.9.2           py311hc37eb10_0    conda-forge
rtree                     1.0.1           py311hcacb13a_2    conda-forge
s3transfer                0.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.3.0           py311h142b183_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.11.1          py311h37ff6ca_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.2              pyh08f2357_0    conda-forge
setuptools                68.0.0          py311haa95532_0  
shapely                   2.0.1           py311h343093d_1    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.10               hfb803bf_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
snuggs                    1.4.7                      py_0    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1        pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0  
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.10.0            h91493d7_0    conda-forge
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.17.0             pyh08f2357_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.2.0              pyha21a80b_0    conda-forge
tiledb                    2.13.2               h3132609_0    conda-forge
tinycss2                  1.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0  
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.2           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.7.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.7.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
typing_utils              0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0  
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
uri-template              1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.15            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1  
vc14_runtime              14.36.32532         hfdfe4a8_17    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.36.32532         h05e6639_17    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webcolors                 1.13               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.38.4          py311haa95532_0  
widgetsnbextension        4.0.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_6    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
xarray                    2023.7.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xarray-spatial            0.3.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.4                h63175ca_2    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xyzservices               2023.7.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.4.2                h8cc25b3_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.9.2           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zict                      3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.16.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h12be248_7    conda-forge
```

Comment: Hi, can you also use rasterio.open and read data in your notebook outside of Dask computation?

Comment: Yes, I can use `rasterio.open` fine in the notebook in general, as well as in Dask clusters on AWS. It's just not working in local Dask clusters.

Comment: I don't see why it fails then, your LocalCluster should use the exact same environment as the one the notebook is using. But maybe there is a Windows trick I don't understand. What happens if you also import rasterio inside the function your submitting to the cluster?

Comment: Right, I don't understand this either-- shouldn't the local cluster be using the same environment? I did try importing rasterio inside the function that I submit to the cluster and it produced the same error.